# Бесконечно повторяющийся ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго всем вечера. Нужна помощь в составлении ajax запроса, который будет бесконечно повторятся. Причем будет повторятся сразу, как получен ответ от php скрипта. Сейчас я использую такой код:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#addurl').load('/addurl.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 
15000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

т.е. код чекает скрипт, через каждые несколько секунд, а требуется постоянно и сразу без задержек.

Очень буду благодарен, тем кто поможет.

Comment: скрипт не серверный, а скорее для локалхоста и им будет пользоваться один человек.
если можно, напишите полный код пожалуйста

Comment: народ, пожалуйста, напишите код, а то я в аякс бум-бум, даже синтаксиса не знаю, готов скинть копеечку отозвавшемуся человеку

Answer (score 4):

На эту тему есть очень интересная [статья](http://abrdev.com/?p=1100), которая может вам помочь.
З.Ы. `setInterval(..., 15000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds` - комментарий жжет).

Answer (score 1):

Хм, а может отказаться от подобной идеи? Вы грузите не только сервер, но и канал. Если у вас будет около 100 пользователей, он еще, возможно, вынесет это. Мне кажется Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону постоянного соединения ([COMET сервер](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))).

Answer (score 1):

Выделить код обращения в отдельную функцию, по загрузке страницы один раз запустить ее. А что бы повторялось, в качестве колбэка нужно указать ту же функцию. Причем и в случае удачи и в случае неудачи, что бы выполнение не слетело.

Comment: Не стоит так делать. Во-первых, растёт call stack и появляется шанс получить, в лучшем случае, утечку памяти. Во-вторых, не стоит забывать что при выполнении javascript все остальные потоки браузера останавливаются и пользователь получит эффект зависшей страницы.

Comment: При чем тут стек вызовов? Это не рекурсия. Функция отрабатывает свой код, загружает документ и сопутствующий код, передает управление (читай минус ячейка стека), затем скрипт подходит к концу исполняемого кода, выполняет новую инструкцию - запускается функция.  Плюс-минус один, циклом.
Асинхронная подгрузка на то и асинхронная, что пока она выполняется, страница продолжает отрабатывать другой код. Колбэк - идеальный выход для четко поставленной топикстарером задачи. Да, это не идеальный вариант, я, например, когда пишу игровые блоки или чат для игры, использую плавающие интервалы обновления.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkNewRequests(number) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url для ajax",
    data: { название передаваемой переменной: ее значение }
}).success(function(msg){
    Делаете нужные манипуляции с пришедшими данными
    checkNewRequests();
}).error(function(msg){
    обрабатываете ошибку
    checkNewRequests();
});
```

На стороне сервера, если не было изменений, необходимых для повторного запуска скрипта, можете не возвращать сразу данные, а дожидаться соответствующего события. В целом это реализация ответа Enpire