# Обновление чата при помощи jquery

Tags: jquery

Предположим есть чат, он представляет собой таблицу из десяти строк: десяти последних сообщений пользователей. Ниже находится форма для нового сообщения. Я могу при помощи jquery не перезагружая страницу добавить введенное сообщений в базу данных, но как обновить таблицу сообщений? имеет ли смысл такая процедура или лучше перезагружать страницу при вызове кнопки "submit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы проблему не решите. =) Походу вам надо почитать про AJAX повнимательнее. Вот был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19597/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81) уже. Вот еще [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19296/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81).

Ройте в сторону comet. Вот неплохую [статейку](http://abrdev.com/?p=1100) кто-то из местных рекомендовал. Мне понравилась. =)

Comment: Да, и непосредственно ответ на вопрос про перезагрузку.
Однозначно чат должен быть на ajax'e. То есть вы подгружаете новые сообщения после их появления в базе( в этом-то и сложность).
У вас у функции ajax есть callback (вообще у всех функций jquery есть callback). То есть то, что выполняется при удачном-неудачном выполнении запроса. А дальше опять отправляете запрос на аяке, и получаете последние сообщения. Вобщет-то лучше сделать так.
Отправить на аяксе post-запрос, а там если все ок, вернуть последние соощения и уже в callback-функции их обработать.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку про Comet, первый раз об этой штуке слышу, попробую изучить.